# 14/3 to add neutral in light switch, is it possible?

Tags: lighting, switch, light-fixture, neutral

I was wondering, is it possible to use 14/3 Romex from the light fixture to the light switch and use the red and black wire to switch a light on and off, and leave the neutral so it fits NEC description of Section 404.2(C) which requires a neutral conductor to be installed in a light switch box.
My plan is to daisy chain power to 3 rooms from light fixture to light fixture with 14/2, then allow the red and black wire from 14/3 Romex to switch the light on and off, while having a neutral in the box.

Your responses are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you already have need or possession of 12/3 and don't want to buy 14/3 *special just for this*, it is permissible to use 12/3 here (or #12 anywhere on a 15A circuit).  You're always allowed to use bigger wire than is required.

Comment: If it's a circuit on a 20A breaker you *need* to use 12/3.

Answer (score 1):

That is what is required now for all light switches.

You use the red and black on the switch screws and place a wire nut on the left over neutral wire.

Before you were allowed to just use a /2 cable and use the white wire as hot if you added black tape to it.

This left no neutral at a light switch which smart switches require.  This meant most people who wanted a smart switch to replace the wiring, which could be a pain.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your quick response. Im pulling out old K&T wiring that someone filled with insulation and its a nightmare.

Comment: **If it's not fed from the light**, the light switch can have 14/2 in and 14/2 out, with the in black being always hot and the out black being switched hot and the whites being neutral. You don't HAVE to have 14/3. That comes from the assumption that power always goes to lights first, which is not always true.

Comment: Doing that much work I think you are made to use 14/3 to the switch to be in code.  If just replacing the switch, you would have the option of keeping 14/2 or replacing it with 14/3.

Comment: These days a switch leg from a fixture box to a switch box requires /3 with ground.  Personally I NEVER wire them that way, it's always power to the switch box and switched power to the fixture box.   Also, regarding 3-way switches, if it's not ridiculously expensive, I will run power in to the first 3 way, then the /3 travelers and ground to the 2nd 3way and from there to the fixture(s) controlled.  That way there is no confusion and no code-taping needed.   If the run from the 2nd 3-way is long, it gets expensive for wire and I'm willing to wire it differently. Good luck on your K&T repl.